# Bootstrap 3 - dropdown menu act as select dropdown (select via keyboard)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap dropdown menu with the list of currencies (short, 3 letters form). I need it to act as a standard select input - access and focus item when the letter on the keyboard is pressed. The doc shows that is possible to use up/down key (this is working), but I need the full functionality. Is this possible?

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price"
                               class="col-md-3 control-label">Choose
                            currency</label>

                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="btn-group" id="currencyButton">
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="currency-system btn btn-default hidden"></button>
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                                        aria-haspopup="true"
                                        aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span
                                        class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="currency-dropdown dropdown-menu" role=menu>
                                    <?php foreach ($currencies as $currency): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a onclick="setCurrency('<?= $currency ?>'); return false;"
                                               href="#"><?= $currency ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <p class="help-block">Choose
                                your preferred currency.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use a select?

Comment: Well it is possible to use keyboard. Provide the doc link please.

Comment: Because of UI requirements (I will loose a lot of time to style the standard select box. Time which I don't have).